# herencia proyecto banco

Tags: java

Hola chicos de nuevo vengo en busca de ustedes esta vez hemos realizado el proyecto banco el cual costa de de cuenta ahorros y cuenta corriente en la clase banco esta el menu de cuenta ahorros sin embargo este menu ya venia realizado y ahora nos han pedido que hagamos el menu de cuenta corriente con su respectivo switch case, lo cual no se como realizar el menu como tal es lo de menos el lio se me hace es en como hacer por ejemplo si escojo cuenta corriente haga lo que la misma o si escojo cuenta ahorros haga lo mismo y luego llamar los metodos de la clase cuenta corriente.
este es el codigo de la clase banco

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
   {
       int saldoInicialAhorros,opc,aux=0,cantidadDepositar,cantidadRetirar;
       Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in); 
       CuentaAhorros cuenta1 = null;
       
       do
       {
           System.out.println("Bienvenido a SU BANCO");
           System.out.println("1. Crear cuenta de ahorros");
           System.out.println("2. Consignar dinero en la cuenta de ahorros");
           System.out.println("3. Retirar de la cuenta de ahorros");
           System.out.println("4. Mostrar información de la cuenta de ahorros");
           System.out.println("5. Salir");
           System.out.print("Escoja su opcion: \t");
           opc = teclado.nextInt();
           
           switch (opc)
           {
           case 1:  System.out.println("Cuenta de ahorros"); 
                    System.out.print("Ingrese saldo inicial para activar su cuenta de ahorros: $ ");
                    saldoInicialAhorros = teclado.nextInt(); 
                    cuenta1 = new CuentaAhorros(saldoInicialAhorros);
                    if(!cuenta1.consultarEstadoCuentaAhorros())
                        System.out.println("Su cuenta no esta activa porque su saldo inicial es inferior a $100.000 ");
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Su cuenta de ahorros ha sido creada");
                        aux = 1;
                    }
                    break;
           case 2:  if(aux == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.print("Ingresar cantidad a consignar: $"); 
                        cantidadDepositar = teclado.nextInt(); 
                        cuenta1.consignar(cantidadDepositar); 
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("No se ha creado la cuenta de ahorros");
                    break;
           case 3:  if(aux == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.print("Ingresar cantidad a retirar: $"); 
                        cantidadRetirar = teclado.nextInt(); 
                        cuenta1.retirar(cantidadRetirar); 
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("No se ha creado la cuenta de ahorros");
                    break;                      
           case 4:  if(aux == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Información de la Cuenta de ahorros"); 
                        cuenta1.mostrarInformacionAhorros(); 
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("No se ha creado la cuenta de ahorros");
                    break;      
           case 5:  System.out.println("Gracias....");
                    break;
           default: System.out.println("Debe ingresar un número entre 1 y 5");
           }
       }while(opc != 5);
```

codig de la clase cuenta corriente

```
package desarrollo.banco.mundo;
```

public class CuentaCorriente extends Banco {

```
/**
 * representa el sobregiro de la cuenta corriente.
 */
public int sobregiro;

/**
 * la mmaxima cantidad permitida de sobregiro.
 */
final int MONTO_MAX = 500000;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Metodo constructor
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * crea la cuenta corriente dado un saldo. Invoca el metodo constructor de Banco.
 * @param saldo. El saldo para crear la cuenta.
 */
public CuentaCorriente(int saldo) 
{
    super(saldo);
    sobregiro = 0;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Metodos de accion
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * retira un saldo de la cuenta corriente. No debe superar el sobregiro permitido.
 * @param cantidad. El valor a retirar
 */
public void retirar(int cantidad) 
{
    
    if (saldo - cantidad < 0) 
    {            
       if(sobregiro - (saldo - cantidad) >= MONTO_MAX)
       {
           System.out.println("No se aprueba el retiro porque supera el monto máximo del sobregiro que es $500.000");
       }
       else 
       {
           sobregiro = sobregiro - (saldo - cantidad); 
           saldo = 0;
       }                   
    } 
    else 
    {
        super.retirar(cantidad);
    }
}

/**
 * realiza una consignacion en la cuenta corriente.
 * @param cantidad. La cantidad a consignar.
 */
public void consignar(int cantidad) 
{
    if (sobregiro > 0) 
    {
        if ( cantidad - sobregiro >= 0) 
        {
            sobregiro = 0;
            saldo = cantidad - sobregiro;
        } 
        else 
        {
            sobregiro = sobregiro - cantidad;
            saldo = 0;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        super.consignar(cantidad);
    }
}


/**
 * muestra la información de la cuenta corriente.
 */
public void mostrarInformacionAhorros() {
    System.out.println("Saldo = $ " + saldo);
    System.out.println("Cantidad de consignaciones = " + cantidadDeConsignaciones);
    System.out.println("Cantidad de retiros = " + cantidadDeRetiros);
    System.out.println("Valor de sogregiro = $" + (cantidadDeConsignaciones + cantidadDeRetiros));
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: @Bicho no, no hay error, solo que no se como hacer el menu de la cuenta corriente y que llame los metodos, soy bastante novato en esto de la programacion la verdad.